# how to fire a jquery child function at the start of parent animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm coding a button that has a CSS arrow which flips up and down every time it's container is clicked.

It looks fine, but i can't figure out how to fire the `toggleClass` function as soon as `slideToggle` has been clicked.

The arrow looks like it is lagging a little because it waits a fraction of a second until the end of the `slideToggle` animation.

Is it possible to make the `toggleClass` fire at the start of the animation rather than the end?

```
$("#content_link").click(function(){
    $("#content").slideToggle("fast",function(){

    $("div#arrow_container").toggleClass('arrow_down');         
    $("div#arrow_container").toggleClass('arrow_up');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if this is what you are asking for but yes call it before the `slideToggle()` function and not inside its callback function

```
 $("#content_link").click(function(){
   $("div#arrow_container").toggleClass('arrow_down')
                           .toggleClass('arrow_up');
   $("#content").slideToggle("fast");

});
```

Comment: Best response because of the inclusion in simplifying .toggleClass and teaching a little extra!

Answer (score 1):

Remove that code from the call back and add it after the slideToggle function call like this

```
$("#content_link").click(function(){
    $("#content").slideToggle("fast");
    $("div#arrow_container").toggleClass('arrow_down');         
    $("div#arrow_container").toggleClass('arrow_up');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a start callback as well:

```
$("header#tag_cat1 div#cat1_content_link").click(function(){
  $("#tag_cat1_content").slideToggle({
    duration: "fast",
    complete: function(){
      $("section.category header > div#cat1_content_link > div").toggleClass('gt_arrow_down_5px');
      $("section.category header > div#cat1_content_link > div").toggleClass('bt_arrow_up_5px');
    },
    start: function() {...}
  });

});
```

Take a look at the second form of [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/#slideToggle-options)